# Recursive sequence, $x_{1} \geq 0, x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_{n}+2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, induction, real-numbers

Recursive sequence, $x_{1} \geq 0, x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_{n}+2}$ and it is requested to **prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=2$**.
This is a common problem, but I found it quite more difficult when the value of $x_1$ is not established, as we cannot say it is a monotonous sequence, and as a part of the exercise we are given a step and a suggestion, which I am pretty sure they can be done by induction. Nevertheless, I am still unable to see the path to prove it.

1. $|x_{n+1}-2|\leq\frac12|x_n-2|, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, and as a suggestion for the problem, note that
2. $|x_n-2|\leq \frac1{2^{n-1}}|x_1-2|, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Comment: If you know how to prove the statement 2, then you can conclude by applying the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Would you mind giving me any suggestions for the statement 2?

Comment: It can be proven by induction and mean value theorem.

Comment: Oh, I think that the person that made the exercise was looking for a different type of answer, given that this is before we see the formal definition of a limit, so I'm guessing it wouldn't be allowed to prove it that way, but thank you for your answer!

Comment: There is no need for the formal definition of limit with the method I propose, I will extend it in an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_n+2}$$

$$x_{n+1}^2=x_n+2$$

$$x_{n+1}^2-4=x_n-2$$

$$(x_{n+1}-2)(x_{n+1}+2)=x_n-2$$

We have $x_{n+1}+2 \ge 2$ since $x_{n+1} \ge 0$.

$$x_{n+1}-2 = \frac{x_n-2}{x_{n+1}+2}$$

$$|x_{n+1}-2| \le \frac{|x_n-2|}{2}$$

Hence we have $$|x_{n+1}-2 | \le \frac{|x_1-2|}{2^n}$$

Hence as $n \to \infty$, we have $x_n \to 2$.

Comment: Way better than my solution. (+1)

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, it was truly helpful and very clear, again thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is presenting a (quite) general method for tackling this kind of problem. For this particular sequence, the answer by the user Siong Thye Goh is much more elegant and elementary.

**Preleminary inequality**

Let $f(x)  =\sqrt{x+2}-2$. We have $f'(x) = \frac 1 {2\sqrt {x+2}}$.
By Mean Value Theorem :

$$|f(x)|=|f(x)-f(2)| \le \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^+} |f'(x)| |x-2|$$

$f'(x)$ is decreasing with $f'(0) = \frac 1 {2 \sqrt 2} < \frac 1 2$.
Finally :

\begin{equation}
f(x) < \frac {|x-2|} 2 
\end{equation}

**Proof of the statement 2 by induction**

Let $x_1 \ge 0$.

We have : $$x_2=\sqrt{x_1+2}.$$

$$|x_2-2| = |\sqrt{x_1+2}-2|\overset{*}< \frac 1 2 |x_1-2|.$$

Where we have applied the preliminary inequality for step with a $*$.

Then, we suppose that, for some $n$ :

$$|x_{n}-2| < \frac 1 {2^{n-1}} |x_1-2|.$$

Thus :
$$|x_{n+1}-2| = |\sqrt{x_n+2}-2|\overset{*}<\frac 1 2 |x_n-2|.$$

Where we have applied the preliminary inequality for step with a $*$.

By applying the inequality just above :

$$|x_{n+1}-2|<\frac 1 {2^{n}} |x_1-2|.$$

Since the inequality was true for $n=2$, by induction it is true for all $n$.

**Conclusion**

$\frac 1 {2^{n}} |x_1-2|$ is a decreasing sequence converging to $0$ as $|x_1-2|$ is just a constant and $\frac 1 {2^{n-1}}$ converges to $0$.

By squeeze theorem, we conclude : $|x_{n+1}-2| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

First, prove that the sequence convergence (not necessarily to 2). Once we know this, let $L = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$. Then we have $L = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n} = \sqrt{2+L}$. This equation has two solutions, but $x_n \geq 0$ so we take the positive solution $L=2$.

Comment: How do you prove that the sequence converges ?

Comment: Then you should give some hints about this in your answer, as it is incomplete.

Comment: The sequence is not monotonous, it is monotonous for a fixed value of $x_1$, when it is greater than 2 it changes its monotony. That's the difference with a fixed value of the first term :c

Comment: @zastenAmir If $0 \leq x_1 \leq 2$, then $x_{n+1} \geq x_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and bounded above by $2$. If $x_1 > 2$, then $x_{n+1} \leq x_n$ for all $n$ sufficiently large and bounded below by $0$.